# How can I convert angularJS directive to Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ionic4

Hi everyone i need to a directive. That should styled to decimal numbers. And i found what exactly i want.  But i didn't run this code on my project.

I'm using:

> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1

That's code:

```
  app.directive('salary', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E'
      , scope: {
          salary: '@'
      }
      , controller: controller
      , controllerAs: 'dvm'
      , bindToController: true
      , template: '<h2><sup>$</sup>{{ dvm.dollar }}<sub>.{{ dvm.cents }}</sub></h2>'
  };

  function controller(){
    var parts = parseFloat(this.salary).toFixed(2).split(/\./);
    this.dollar = parts[0];
    this.cents = parts[1];
  }
});
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Em5SSeHBQBffHvQS8E1z?p=preview)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yilmaz check my answer for a equivalent code in Angular 6/typescript.

Comment: You should have to specify angular JS to Angular(typescript) properly not angular js to typescript. You can write angular js code in typscript also.

Comment: hey @jameelM thanks for your comment. I'm newbie in angular and ionic. That's my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a directive with template that can be displayed in the UI with a selector tag, hence you can use a equivalent `Component` in Angular 6(or anything greater than 2x version). Here is the equivalent code in typescript/Angular 6

**salary.component.ts**

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'salary',
  templateUrl: './salary.component.html'
})
export class SalaryComponent  implements OnInit{
  salary:string = "9033";
  dollar:string; 
  cents:string;
  ngOnInit(){
    let parts = parseFloat(this.salary).toFixed(2).split(/\./);
    this.dollar = parts[0];
    this.cents = parts[1];
  }

}
```

**salary.component.html**

```
<h2><sup>$</sup>{{ dollar }}<sub>.{{ cents }}</sub></h2>
```

**usage**

```
<salary></salary>
```

### if you want to set the value of salary dynamically then you need to use the `@Input()` decorator to set the value of the property from parent component like below -

```
@Input() formattedSalary:string = "";
```

and use it in the HTML like -

```
<salary [formattedSalary]="9033"></salary>
```

Here is a working example in Angular 6

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-tagnx9

Comment: OP was asking angularJS not angular.

Comment: @JameelM it was mentioned in typescript , So the OP needs to confirm Angular or Angularjs is required

Comment: check his tag and syntax of the source code. You can write angular js using typescript also.